# Find connected sub graphs of a super graph using Orient DB

Tags: orientdb

I am just starting to work with Orient and was looking for a way to extract all the connected components (sub graphs) of a (super) graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29 .
 That is, each extracted item is a sub graph in which any two vertices are connected to each other by paths, and which is connected to no additional vertices in the super graph.
I was interesting in doing the retrieval using Orient DB SQL (possibly Match, Traverse)? I attempted several using Natch and Traverse but was not able to get the results. I am using Orient DB 2.2.22 community edition.

In my test case I have a super graph with 11 Nodes and 14 edges.  Nine of the Nodes are connected, and 2 others are connected only to each other. I want to issue a query and be able to retrieve the 2 sub graphs. The nodes have class=> "Group" and the Edges have class = "Overlaps".

I tried this as a first cut: *SELECT $path FROM ( TRAVERSE both('Overlaps') FROM Groups WHILE $depth <= 100 )* but that brought back a set of paths. 
I also attempted using Match but did get the results I needed.
There must be a way to select elements of the paths that are connected and then for each connected set aggregate those nodes into distinct sets.

I would appreciate any suggestions and or examples which can help me solve this problems.

Thanks
JGZ

Comment: Hi, if I understood well, your query should return all the nodes of the class Group and this nodes has to be connected to each other through Overlps edges, am I right?

Comment: hello, yes, out of the 11 nodes, 9 are connected to each other as a connected sub graph and the other 2 are connected only to each other, and not to any of the others. What I need is to extract 2 sub-graphs back out where one has 9 nodes and the other has 2. Thanks JGZ

Answer (score 2):

To test your case I created this example (pls correct me if is wrong):

[image]

and if I execute this query:

```
select $a as sub_graph_one,$b as sub_graph_two
LET $a = (select @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:*:-1') from Group where name = 'group001'),
$b = (select @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:*:-1') from Group where name = 'group008')
```

and this is what I get:

[image]

the first contains the 9 nodes and the second one the other two nodes.

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Hello, your scenario is exactly what I was looking at, and it is helpful.  The difference is that in my scenario I do not know ahead of time what groups are where so I cannot assume to start at a specific node. This solution requires starting at 'group001' and also then starting at 'group008' and then it gets the connected members. In my case I would not know ahead of time and if I randomly started a traversal at some node, I woul  only get the connected group for that one. Thanks JGZ